# RewriteRule not working below

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The below Rewrite Rules are not working

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^about/?$    /about.php    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$    /contact.php    [NC,L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

But if I do this it works

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^about-us/?$    /about.php    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$    /contact.php    [NC,L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Thank

Comment: What do you mean by **not working** ? Does it return a 404 error?

Comment: Haven't figure out why this is not working. Is there another way to do the rewrite?<BR><BR>


I added the following php code to my error page to accomplish the redirect in the mean time<BR>

<code>
    if (stripos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 'about') !== false) {
        header("Location: /about-us");
        exit;
    }elseif (stripos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 'contact') !== false) {
        header("Location: /contact-us");
        exit;
    }
</code>


Sorry I don’t know how to format the comments